# How to implement the gmail notification?

Tags: android, notifications, slidingdrawer

I have a scenario wherein in need to implement a similar effect like the one in gmail app notification.

while closing the notification if you see in the screenshot the archive and reply view are overlapped by the email textview.

Please suggest any ideas

Thanks

[image: while closing]
[image: when closed]

Comment: This is the default behaviour for the new Notifications in Jelly bean and above. I don't think you need to add anything extra.

Comment: May be, i need to implement the same drag or functionality on a view  how can i do that?

Comment: Its the basic functionality of an expandable notification. Just refer the android developers site to see how the Notifications work in 4.2+

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update notifications once you've created them. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a big view style to your notification and the dragging mechanism will be added for you. Note this will only work starting from Jelly Bean 4.1.

This guide will be of some help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html